# ¿Como comparar roles en discord.js v13.6.0?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Mi code esta así

```
if(message.member.roles.highest(message.mentions.users.first().highestRole)<1)
```

Me tira error, ¿que hago?

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español!  Por favor, haz el [tour] y aprende cómo funciona este sitio formulando tu pregunta adecuadamente en [ask]. Un primer paso es decirnos el error que te da.

Comment: Prueba a sacar el '<1' fuera del paréntesis

Comment: "Me tira error, ¿que hago?" Investigar, buscar el error en google, estudiarlo para comprenderlo, intentar repararlo, leer la documentación, debugging, intentar otra forma, leer más documentación, hacer más debugging. Si todo lo anterior falla, volver aquí con **DETALLES DE LO QUE INTENTASTE**